# android - videoView.setOnCompletionListener called twice

Tags: android, android-videoview, countdowntimer

I am playing a video in videoview. On its completion I have to start a CountdownTimer. The method setOnCompletionListener of videoview is called twice and hence the code to start the timer runs twice.

Do I need to call any other method to do the task?

Code:

```
VideoView videoView;
private MediaController controller;

 private void setupView(View view){
videoView = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
controller = new MediaController(getActivity());
controller.setAnchorView(videoView);


videoView.setMediaController(null);
    videoView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
    videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            stopVideoViewTimer();
            startExcerciseDetailTimer();
        }
    });
playCurrentVideo();
}
private void playCurrentVideo() {

if (prepareVideo()) {
            roundTimeLayoutCombos.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            excerciseTimerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            restTimeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            videoLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    updateExerciseLayout();
                videoView.start();
        }
}

private Boolean prepareVideo() {
    Boolean prepared = false;
        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/folder/xyz.mp4";
        videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(filePath));
        videoView.requestFocus();
        prepared = true;

    return prepared;
}
```

Comment: in case of `setOnCompletionListener() ` - The callback will be called both in the case where the video completes successfully, and if playback terminates due to an error. are you sure there is no error ?

Comment: Yes the complete video is played with no error.

Comment: @PraneetKumar : have you found solution for it ?